# Flutter reuse views

Tags: gridview, dart, flutter

I'm new to Flutter development and just started with a gridViewWidget. In my gridview, I have FlashCardList and FlashCards. In the highest level, it should show FlashCardList and onTap on any of the objects, it should show another gridview with the flashcards associated with the flashCardList category. My question is, do I need to create a new gridViewWidget just for the FlashCards and repeat 90% of the code or can I reuse the existing widget? I'm able to do this in iOS by calling the same view again and passing a few values so the child view knows to pull a different set of data but I'm not sure how I can do that with a futurebuilder that requests the type to be predefined and the gridView Builder that requires the items to be predefined as well. Here's my code:

```
 class GridViewWidget extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  createState() => new GridViewState();

}

class GridViewState extends State<GridViewWidget>{

  List<Sound> sound;
  List<FlashCardList> flashCardList;
  List<FlashCards> flashCards;


  @override
  void initState(){
    debugPrint ('debug main.dart');
    super.initState();

  }

  Future<List<FlashCards>> fetchFlashCards() async{
    final response = await http.get('some url');
    //debugPrint (response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = json.decode(response.body);
      var flashCardsData = data["FlashCards"] as List;
      flashCards = flashCardsData.map<FlashCards>((json) => FlashCards.fromJson(json)).toList();
      debugPrint("Did get data: ${flashCards.first.name}");
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
    //objects = [sound, flashCardList, flashCards].expand((x) => x).toList();
    return flashCards;
  }

  Future<List<FlashCardList>> fetchFlashCardList() async{
    final response = await http.get('some url');
    //debugPrint (response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = json.decode(response.body);
      var flashCardListData = data["FlashCardList"] as List;
      flashCardList = flashCardListData.map<FlashCardList>((json) => FlashCardList.fromJson(json)).toList();
      debugPrint("Did get data: ${flashCardList.first.name}");
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
    //objects = [sound, flashCardList, flashCards].expand((x) => x).toList();
    return flashCardList;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: new Text(Strings.pageTitle),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<FlashCardList>>(
        future: fetchFlashCardList(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Object>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError)
            return new Text(
              '${snapshot.error}',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
            );
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.none:
              return new Text('Input a URL to start');
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return new Center(child: new CircularProgressIndicator());
            case ConnectionState.active:
              return new Text('');
            case ConnectionState.done:
                return new GridView.builder(
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                      maxCrossAxisExtent: 200.0,
                      childAspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height)),
                  itemCount: flashCardList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return _getGridItemUI(context, flashCardList[index]);

                    /*return GridTile(header: Text("FlashCards"),
                        child: Text(
                        flashCards[index].name, textAlign: TextAlign.center));*/

                  },
                );
          }
        }
      ),
    );
  }

  _getGridItemUI(BuildContext context, FlashCardList item){
    return new InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        _showSnackBar(context, item);
      },
      child: new Card(
        child: new Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[

              new Image(image: new CachedNetworkImageProvider("some url" + item.image)),
              /*new Expanded(
                child:new Center(
                  child: new Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                      new Expanded(
                        child: AutoSizeText(
                          item.name, maxLines: 1,
                        )
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              )*/
            ],
        ),
        elevation: 2.0,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      )
    );
  }

  _showSnackBar(BuildContext context, FlashCardList item){

  }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the GridViewWidget generic to solve the type issue or pass a parameter to differentiate between flash and flashcards but it's not an ideal solution. And I recommend not to put data fetching logic inside your widgets.

Comment: thanks so the ideal solution would be to have 2 gridview widgets?

Comment: In this case if you extract away the business logic the amount of code you will duplicate will be minimal. But again this totally depends on your requirements if you are sure these two views (flashcardList and list details) won't have different requirements in the future go with a single gridView, but if there is even a slight change I would chose two views. You can extract the _getGridItemUI to a widget and use it on both gridviews